# Do vibrational frequencies produced from sound pass through your entire body? from one side to another?

Tags: acoustics, biophysics, vibrations, absorption, perception

when there is a noise by me, i feel the vibration on my skin from the direction it’s coming, it moves into my body. a wall of what sound would feel like passing through me. i perceive it as container of vibration floating in mid air that passes through me like a ghost. if a car drives past me i can feel the vibrations come into me and pass through like an energy. sometimes i feel my body physically react and become tense to the uncomfortability of the vibration hitting my body, when this happens it feels as though it harbours in my body (until released). is this possible? it’s not only in situations as intense as a car passing. i feel the vibration of a voice as someone speaks to me too, if it’s face on i feel it hit my whole front not only my ears. just wondering if what i am perceiving to be is scientifically viable

Answer (score 3):

You're right: sound passes through your body. However, it doesn't couple efficiently from air into or out of your body, so it has to be relatively intense for you to feel it. The relatively high density of your body limits the coupling.

Your outer ear is a specialized structure for efficiently coupling sound to your middle ear. Your middle ear is a specialized structure for coupling the resulting vibrations to your inner ear. This is why your ears are more sensitive to sound than the rest of your body.

Medical ultrasonic imaging works by avoiding coupling through air: a solid transducer touches the body, achieving efficient coupling.